# Allow to run from Sunday to Friday?

Tags: go, time, process, weekday

The following PHP code that allows a process to only run between certain times.  How would this be done in GoLang?

```
$curdate = date('Y-m-d');
$mydate=getdate(strtotime($curdate));
if ( $mydate['wday'] === 0 ) {
  if ( date('H') < 15 ) { exit; }; // This is for 0 Sunday!!!
}
if ( $mydate['wday'] === 5 ) {
  if ( date('H') > 19 ) { exit; }; // This is for 5 Friday!!!
}
if ( $mydate['wday'] === 6 ) {
  exit;  // This is for 6 Saturday //
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the same thing:

```
now := time.Now()
day := now.Weekday()
hr  := now.Hour()

if day == 0 {
    if hr < 15 { os.Exit(0) }
} 
if day == 5 {
    if hr > 19 { os.Exit(0) }
}
if day == 6 {
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Where similarly, each day can be represented by an integer (0 - 6).

Note that to use `time` and `os` you will need to call

```
import "time"
import "os"
```

See [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) for more about Golang time.

Comment: In go how would you verify the process is already running if it called to start?  So the process would not have more than one running instance?

Comment: @user2777145 Sorry but you will have to do some research or ask a seperate question as I don't know

Comment: No problem my fix is to ps | grep for process before starting process to verify it is not running.